# Jira Upgrade login failure

Tags: authentication, upgrade, jira

I'm trying to upgrade to JIRA 4.1.2.

I did a back up on the old version and saved it in backup.xml. I then went to the new version and imported that backup.xml file. I checked my database it everything seems to have loaded fine but It wont let me login for some reason. It keeps saying my credentials are wrong. Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.  The active directory settings need to be manually changed for the new version.